# Facebook login - detect user logged in without PHP-SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I've built custom login flow for facebook login according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/ ...

Is it enaugh to consider user as facebook-valid-user-logged-in if the access_token retrieval (Exchanging code for an access token) was successful (no GET error)?

Is facebook access_token something unique to the user and something that can only be "generated by the user"?

Or should I try to retrieve user info with that access_token and after successfully checking it(that it has information requested in permission e.g. email) then only after that consider him as facebook-valid-user-logged-in?

PS: I do not want to use Facebook PHP-SDK

Comment: Can I ask why you do not want to use the SDK?

Comment: @Lix It is much more clearer and shorter and I want it to be similar to the rest of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a requirement to not use an official SDK then I would say that you *should* validate the tokens you retrieve by querying `/me`.

This is the best way to make sure that you are dealing with a valid token as it is verified by Facebook when you use it for a request.

If the token you are using is not valid, you'll get a response similar to this:

```
{
  error: {
    message: "Invalid OAuth access token.",
    type: "OAuthException",
    code: 190
  }
}
```

User access tokens *are* unique per user **and** per application. Each application will return a different token for the same user.

Application access tokens are unique per application and do not require any requests to Facebook in order to retrieve them - they are just a concatenation between the app_id and app_secret: `app_id|app_secret` as [mentioned in the documentation:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)

> There is another method to make calls to the Graph API that doesn't require using a generated app token. You can just pass your app id and app secret as the access_token parameter when you make a call:
>
> `http://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret`
>
> The choice to use a generated access token vs. this method depends on where you hide your app secret.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that /me wont be provided if the access_token is invalid ? btw: I know about the app acc token and ways how to retrieve it, but it is good point it out :)

Comment: @jave.web - Yep, you can try it out by opening up an incognito window and trying to hit `https://graph.facebook.com/SOME_ID/?access_token=some_random_string`.

Comment: If anyone else would wonder - quering `/me` has no user id in it and is in a format::::::::::: `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=YourUniqueUserAccessToken` - no user id, just the access_token :) - it is better since `/me` (unlike classic `graph.facebook.com/SOME_ID`) CANT be retrieved without access_token